# How to avoid malicious requests vulnerability

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have this application scanned for security vulnerability and the result shows that on one of the page changes were applied to the original request and the application found to be vulnerable to malicious requests. To fix this recommendation is to decline these malicious requests. How can I check in this page that all requests coming are from the systems other pages only?

I am using VS 2005 and .Net 2.0 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set validateRequest="true" in Page directive